# can i have a virtual CD DRIVE in lubuntu 13.10

Tags: lubuntu

I don't have a CD drive in my computer and I use bootable Pendrives to boot up my PC. Now, my pen drive is lost so, can I have a bootable CD drive which can install Operating systems like in oracle virtual box?

Comment: Just to clarify you want to use a virtual drive to install an operating system on the physical machine?

Comment: yes @JulianStirling

Comment: The problem here is that the virtual CD is is a program running in an operating system, so you can't boot from it because it only exists once the operating system is booted. You can probably make a bootable install partition. Best plan is to buy another USB drive (I think it is possible to actually make a new partition on the hard-drive and install from there, but that is not as simple).

Comment: @JulianStirling here I agree with you.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot using this. i think its my last boot as i think i did an error bye! HAVMRFPAUSLD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear you can't have a virtual CD drive from which you can boot. There is a nice program `gmount-iso` that lets you mount image files but it will not help at boot time.

[Julian Stirling](https://askubuntu.com/users/139634/julian-stirling) aptly described the reason in the comment above:

> The problem here is that the virtual CD is is a program running in an operating system, so you can't boot from it because it only exists once the operating system is booted.